# Corrupted file when opened in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, file, dreamweaver

I am having an issue  with a web project that was done by someone else. 
I was given the task to modify some pages (like the prices in the store, nothing complicated) but when I load the project in Dreamweaver some of the pages are corrupted. Those pages look fine in the browser as well as when I open the source code in a basic txt editor. 
Anyone knows what would cause this?

I do not think it matters, but those files contain HTML and javascript.

Comment: How do you mean 'corrupted'? Perhaps they are using some other linebreaks than dreamweaver.

Comment: This is a little bit offtopic, but i would recommend to use different text editor, for example `notepad++` you would never get this kind of problem again

Comment: @Linas - I concur! Notepad++ FOR THE WIN!

Comment: @KristerAndersson - the code inside the file is something like Chinese characters. But the same file looks just fine in the browser as well as when I open it using a simple txt editor (perhaps like Textpad++ or notepad++).

Comment: It sounds like Dreamweaver's encoding detection is failing. IIRC Dreamweaver has an option in the File Open dialog that lets you force the encoding used to open the document. I would expect the file to be saved in UTF-8. If in doubt, ask the original author.

Comment: @RCC let us know, if your problem still persist. And, illustrate your problem in more specific.

Comment: Maybe they had some content in another language? I remember when I had to deal with content of another language I needed to go into windows font folder and enable that language's font in order to view the content in DW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you said..

> Those pages look fine in the browser as well as when I open the source
>   code in a basic txt editor

Mostly, this type of problem cause due to the file format (i mean file standard). So, better to open it in txt editor and copy your code and make new file in Dreamweaver with appropriate extension and paste your code in it.

Answer (score 1):

It is risky to edit a site design in any program besides the one used to create your site. Switching to a different brand of editor can cause corruption in the source code. I'm not sure what exactly was originally used to create the code, but this could be the problem

I recommend importing to your new editor and publishing to a test folder to be sure there is no corruption.